# How to limit the amount of requests per ip connection in socket programming in python?

Tags: python, sockets, server, python-requests, ddos

I'm developing a Firewall for math server(Tcp server using sockets) in python to prevent the server from Distributed denial of service attack as an mini project.This is my code

```
    import socket
    import re
    from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE
    from threading import Thread

def start_new_math_thread(conn, addr):
    t = MathServerCommunicationThread(conn, addr)
    t.start()

class ProcessOutputThread(Thread): #OOPS
    def __init__(self, proc, conn):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.proc = proc
        self.conn = conn
        
    def run(self):
        while not self.proc.stdout.closed and not self.conn._closed:
            try:
                self.conn.sendall(self.proc.stdout.readline())
            except:
                pass
            
class MathServerCommunicationThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn, addr):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = conn
        self.addr = addr
    
    def run(self):
        self.conn.sendall("Simple Math Server developed by LAHTP Version-2.o ('integrated with Firewall' ) \n\nGive any math expressions, and I will answer you...\U0001F609 \n\n$ ".encode())


        p = Popen(['bc'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
        output = ProcessOutputThread(p, self.conn)
        output.start()

        while not p.stdout.closed or not self.conn._closed:
            try:
                data = self.conn.recv(1024)

                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    try:
                        data = data.decode()
                        query = data.strip()
                        if query == 'quit' or query == 'exit':
                            print("{} disconnected...!".format(addr[0]))
                            con.remove(addr[0])
                            p.communicate(query.encode(), timeout=1)
                            if p.poll() is not None:
                                break
                            
                        query = query + '\n'
                        p.stdin.write(query.encode())
                        p.stdin.flush()
                        if not re.match("^[0-9|+|-|*|/|^|=]{1,15}$",query):
                            conn.send(b"Only Integers are allowed & it should range between 0to15 digits\n")
                            self.conn.close()
                            print ("{} is trying to exploit the resources so the connection is closed.".format(addr[0]))
                            con.remove(addr[0])
                        else:
                          pass
                    except:
                        pass
            except:
                pass
        self.conn.close()

HOST = ''
PORT = 8877
con=[]

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print("Server initialized\n Waiting for the incoming connections...")
s.listen()
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    start_new_math_thread(conn, addr)
    if addr[0] in con:
        print("connection rejected from {}:{}".format(addr[0],addr[1]))
        conn.close()
    else:
        con.append(addr[0])
        print("connection accepted from {}:{}".format(addr[0],addr[1]))
```

i want to limit the amount of request from user by giving the limitaion to the requests per ip connection per minute(in socket programming). I searched many sources to implement this, but i am unable to find this, Is this possible?if yes,what am i should do?

Comment: Could be helpful: https://pypi.org/project/pyrate-limiter/

Comment: Python or user space applications in general are not the best way to implemented rate limiting for connections. At the time the user space program gets involved the connection is already accepted by the OS kernel. All what the user space program could do now is to close it.

It performs much better to let the OS kernel handle such limits already. See for example [Limit max connections per IP address and new connections per second with iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139285/) on how to do this with Linux iptables.